# Getting "STDERR message(s)..." message when running sp_execute_external_script SP in SQL Server 2017 using R

Tags: sql-server-2017, microsoft-r

I recently installed SQL Server 2017 on my machine and configured both Python & R services.

When running below code I am getting "STDERR" message along with the actual output.

Can someone please help me understand why I'm getting that error and how to fix it? Thanks in advance.

```
exec sp_execute_external_script
     @language=N'R'
   , @script=N'print(R.version)'
go
```

[STDERR Error message(s)...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lx6BB.jpg)

Comment: What OS is the SQL Server running on, Win10 or Win Server? I just did a new SQL 2017 installation and I do not get the error. Oh, whe you installed SQL, did you install bot In Database Analytics as well as Standalone?

Comment: Hi Niels, I am using Windows 10 Home OS and I installed Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-GDR) (KB4505224) - 14.0.2027.2 (X64)   Jun 15 2019 00:26:19   Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation  Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Home 10.0 <X64> (Build 18362: ). Also, while installing SQL Server 2017 I have enabled/checked the Database Analytics feature as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are running SQL server 2017 CU13, (or later CU), as what you see is a bug introduced in CU13. What you see should not be a problem, it is a warning, and t is due to  an incompatibility with the R package CompatibilityAPI.

The anwwer is also in this thread: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6ab7a0ca-836f-4d18-ac49-3239d610413d/getting-quotstderr-messages-from-external-scriptquot-message-showing?forum=MicrosoftR

Comment: Means, will have to wait until MS releases the fix for that bug! In that case, I will continue like this, but in case if you find any information, in future, about fixing this bug please do share it here so that I can follow the same to resolve it. Thanks for your help Nelis.

Comment: @kyeleswarapu, no probs. But once again, as far as I can tell, the bug does not cause any issues - other than the warning message you see.